# how to query Oracle column of Date with timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 1 with below structure:

```
workflow_name varchar2(50)
session_name  varchar2(50)
actual_start  Date
```

TableData look like below:

```
workflow1  session1  21-JAN-16 21:30:49
```

now i want to run query at 30min. if i am running at 10am means i want to find out how many sessions run from 9.30am to 9.59am

i will write my query

```
select count(*) from table1
where workflowname ='workflow1'
and sessionname ='sessionname1'
and actual_start should between 9.30am to 9.59am
```

how do i code in for actual_start should between 9.30am to 9.59am?

thanks

Comment: you say timestamp but you show the type as date.  Which is it?

Comment: are you looking for 48 different hardcoded values if running every 30 minutes? Or something more dynamic? Is it going to be automated to run and assume that it wants the exact thirty minute interval from the most immediately preceding hour or half-hour mark? Please be clearer about your requirements

Comment: i will keep this query in session and it is scheduled to run every 30 min in a day. if the number of session is less than 21, there is some issue, i will go and look at my workflow in PROD.

Comment: added an answer that will give you the rows you need for calendar half hours. You can just change the SELECT * to a SELECT COUNT(*) if all you want is the count of rows to check against your benchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Fixed error in endpoint calculations!**

At any given moment in time, this will give the most recently passed half hour interval:

```
select case when sysdate - trunc(sysdate,'HH') > (30/1440) then trunc(sysdate,'HH') 
        else trunc(sysdate,'HH')- (30/1440) end as start_point
      ,case when sysdate - trunc(sysdate,'HH') > (30/1440) then trunc(sysdate,'HH') + (30/1440)
        else trunc(sysdate,'HH') end as end_point  
from dual
```

so at 10:01 it will give today's 9:30 - 10:00, and at 10:40 it will give today's 10:00 - 10:30.

So you just need to look for data in that range (You will need to figure out where the end-points fall as one end needs to be inclusive and the other exclusive to avoid a row being counted twice. I made the lower bound inclusive in my example):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE actual_start_date >= (select case when sysdate - trunc(sysdate,'HH') > (30/1440) then trunc(sysdate,'HH') 
                             else trunc(sysdate,'HH')- (30/1440) end
                            FROM DUAL)
AND actual_start_date < (SELECT case when sysdate - trunc(sysdate,'HH') > (30/1440) then trunc(sysdate,'HH') + (30/1440) 
                           else trunc(sysdate,'HH') end 
                          from dual)
```

And now you will get the most recently proceeding half hour whenever you run it.

If you want the REALLY simple query - just get rows for the last 30 minutes from RIGHT NOW, then just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE actual_start_date >= (sysdate - (30/1440));
```

Comment: This solution perfectly fits to my requirements. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Simpler is almost always better - as long as it does what it needs to. Cheers.